# Programmatically change bold, underline, italic of text selection using CKEditor API

Tags: ckeditor, rich-text-editor, richtext, underline

I'm using my own UI to drive CKEditor's API. The following API works to toggle the selected text with bold and italic respectively, but does not work for underline.

```
editorInstance.execCommand( 'bold' );
editorInstance.execCommand( 'italic' );
editorInstance.execCommand( 'underline' ); // does not work
```

I've checked the source and have verified that the underline command is indeed present.

How do I programmatically underline selected text using CKEditor?

Answer (score 2):

You're dealing here with the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter). Precisely with its effect on commands' states. In the standard preset, which I assume you use, the Underline button is [removed from toolbar](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-presets/blob/master/presets/standard-ckeditor-config.js#L31) and therefore the related command is disabled. When command is disabled, it cannot be executed.

You can verify this with:

```
editor.getCommand( 'underline' ).state == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED;
```

I anticipate that you'll try to remove the entire toolbar plugin. To save you some time - it's the toolbar plugin what registers most of the features (by registering enabled buttons). So if you remove the toolbar, then all features (commands are part of features) which are registered this way will be disabled. You should find this guide helpful - [Plugins integration with the ACF](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_integration_with_acf).

Comment: So if I were to remove the entire toolbar plugin, would that mean I have to implement each feature back in? I'm trying to learn my way around CKEditor, but I assume that the toolbar plugin simply registers for what pieces of functionality it wants to expose, and does not actually implement the behaviour of each feature. This would then allow someone to come in, build their own UI, register for wanted features, and execute commands.

Comment: I've posted a new question that goes intoa bit more detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030449/use-my-existing-rich-text-ui-with-ckeditor-apis